# Searching my code with regex

Tags: regex, search, text-editor

It happens all the time, I would need to scan my code for places where I have two or more of the same keywords. 
For example `$json["VALID"]`
So, I would need to find `json`, and `VALID`.

Some places in the code may contain:

```
//    a = $json['VALID']; // (note the apostrophes)
```

(I am using EditPlus which is a great text editor, letting me use regex in my searches)

What would be the string in the regex to find json and VALID (in this example) ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
\$json\[["']VALID['"]\]
```

Comment: Thanks, would you know how would I find *Any* character between json and VALID ?

Comment: `\$json.*VALID` but than it could be 1000 characters .. use `\$json.{1,10}VALID` to limit it to 1 till 10

Answer (score 4):

wound find `$json<2 character>VALID`

```
\$json.{2}VALID
```

Comment: Thanks for the great and quick answer, *Kirill* answered first so I marked him as answered, appreciate your help!